# Проблема с парсингом в Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

На сайте есть игрок, и причина, по которой он не может сыграть, в данном случае травма. Если игрока я спарсить могу с помощью: `name = driver.find_element("css selector", ".heading__name").text`, то что сделать, чтоб достать и его травму, по xpath не получается. Надо чтоб было так: Райан Бертран (Травма колена).
HTML код:

```
<div class="heading__title">
        <div class="heading__name">Райан Бертран</div>
        <svg class="heading__absence" onmouseover="if (typeof tt != 'undefined' &amp;&amp; tt !== null) { tt.show(this, event); }" onmouseout="if (typeof tt != 'undefined' &amp;&amp; tt !== null) { tt.hide(this); }">
            <title>Травма колена</title>
            <use xlink:href="/res/_fs/image/13_symbols/incident.svg#injury"></use>
        </svg>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас в блоке `<svg...`  текстовый блок только один, то достаточно использовать `css selector`:

```
injury = driver.find_element("css selector", ".heading__absence").text
```

Если нет, то посложнее будет. Так как у элементов svg свое пространство имен, то просто используя .XPATH до них не добраться [пространство имен svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54236662/unable-to-locate-svg-elements-through-xpath-on-kendo-ui-chart/54237441#54237441:%7E:text=As%20the%20desired%20elements).

```
injury = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='heading__title']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='title']").text
```

Answer (score 0):

Из других ваших вопросов я понял, что речь идёт об этой странице: https://www.soccerstand.com/ru/player/castrovilli-gaetano/ALBpOZPH/

Код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.soccerstand.com/ru/player/castrovilli-gaetano/ALBpOZPH/")
name = driver.find_element("css selector", ".heading__name").text
injury = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.heading__absence title').get_attribute("innerHTML")
print(name, injury)
```